# I am doing performance investigation for an android application for its GPU using systrace. What does “GPU completion” thread in systrace means

Tags: android, gpu, tensorflow-lite, systrace, android-profiler

I see that "GPU completion" thread goes into idle mode after a longer time when app is launched if there is tflite model initialisation at app launch. Does it state a higher usage of GPU in android device? Idle state means that GPU usage is not required at that time?

Comment: What exact process did you follow to get the systrace information? Also, can you post a screenshot of what it looks like?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: just wanted to clarify that `GPU Completion` is NOT a real thread. It's just a way by systrace to organize trace events in the form of a thread.

**Original Answer:**

`GPU Completion` is a thread that waits for GPU work in your app process. The systrace trace event `waiting for GPU completion` starts when `queueBuffer` is sent to the GPU and ends when the GPU completes the work.

It doesn't mean GPU is busy during the entire event. If you want to monitor actual GPU usage, you might want to try [Android Graphics Inspector](https://gpuinspector.dev/). It's geared towards game developers but could be useful in this case as well.